# Linearization of a fact about functions between finite sets

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, co.combinatorics

Suppose $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are finite sets.  If we have a function
$$f : X \longrightarrow Y$$
and another
$$g : Y \longrightarrow Z$$
then the composite function $g \circ f$ has the property that
$$ |\mbox{Im} ( g \circ f )| \leq |Y|. $$

If we replace $f$ by a formal linear combination of functions $X \longrightarrow Y$, and $g$ by a formal linear combination of functions $Y \longrightarrow Z$, then we may "compose" these formal combinations (enforcing the distributive law) to obtain a linear combination of functions $X \longrightarrow Z$, none of which have image exceeding $|Y|$ in cardinality.

My question is the converse: can any such linear combination be obtained?

I posted this question at math.stackexchange, but there are no responses after a week:
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/97513/22621

Comment: What do you mean by the "image" of a formal linear combination of functions?

Comment: He doesn't speak of such an image. He only mentions images of each of these functions.

Comment: Right. Thanks. I need to work on my English. 

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your notion of a formal linear combination in this context, since X, Y, and Z are just sets. Have you defined + and scalar multiplication on the set of maps from X to Y?  Or are you really interested in *formal* linear combinations?  For example, if $f_1$ and $f_2$ are two maps from X to Y, is $f_1 + f_2$ simply some other (unspecified) map from X to Y?

Comment: By formalizing, he replaces a map f with a formal symbol F.  There is no map f + g, but there is a formal sum: one of F plus one of G.
(I thought of saying one times instead of one of, but that might get confused with the composition.)  I am unclear if in his question the linear combination to be decompositioned is given as a formal sum of. H circle F terms, or if he has symbols K for maps k and rules that say K can be any one of (some set of)l these terms H ccircle F.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman,  2012.01.16

Comment: @Gerhard Paseman I intend the addition to be formal, but the composition to be usual composition of functions.  In other words, the formal sum to be decomposed is a sum of functions X to Z without any specified factorization of each function.

Comment: But you have to be careful.  You want a formal sum of a subset of functions from X to Z such that each summand is (some scalar multiple of) a map with image of size at most the size of Y; the summands aren't fully arbitrary.  Or have you something else in mind?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman,  2012.01.16

Comment: @Gerhard Paseman You have it correct.  I was trying to convey that with the word "converse."

Comment: Anyway, from my point of view the rules are implicit: if k is a map which is identical with the composition g(f()), then one can write K = G circle F formally. You just want to find the appropriate formal factors, if there are any, and you don't care how they are chosen; that is my reading of the problem, and is like the second choice in my comment above.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.01.16 

Answer (score 3):

No.  Consider e.g. the case $X = Z = \{1,2,3\}$, $Y = \{1,2\}$, and the formal linear combination $h_1 + h_2$ where $h_1(1) = h_1(2)=1$, $h_1(3)=2$, $h_2(1)=h_2(3)=2$, $h_2(2)=3$.
If $h_1 = g_1 \circ f_1$, we must have $f_1(1) = f_1(2) \ne f_3(3)$ and 
$\text{Im}(g_1) = \{1,2\}$.  Similarly if $h_2 = g_2 \circ f_2$ we must have $f_2(1)=f_2(3) \ne f(2(2)$ and $\text{Im}(g_2) = \{2,3\}$.  But $h_{12} = g_2 \circ f_1$, which would have
$h_{12}(1) = h_{12}(2)$ and $\text{Im}(h_{12}) = \{2,3\}$, and similarly $h_{21} = g_1 \circ f_2$, are not part of this formal linear combination.

Comment: As I understand the question (but I misunderstood it already a few hours ago), he is asking if $h_1+h_2$ could perhaps be written in the form $(\sum_i  \lambda_i g_i) \circ (\sum_j \mu_j f_j)$.

Comment: My computer tells me that this example is correct,  i.e. h_1+h_2 cannot be factored in the manner Goldstern has written.

Comment: I hesitate to accept the answer, though, since this argument only shows that the factorization cannot have the form (g_1+g_2)(f_1+f_2) where g_1 f_1 = h_1 and g_2 f_2 = h_2.

Comment: ...you had a way to check it by computer? Man, I could have told you that was a probable counterexample...

Comment: Add me to the list of people who would want to know how to check things like that on a computer.

Comment: I'm embarrassed I never checked.  I was too busy assuming it was true :(.

@darij grinberg It's a finite-dimensional problem over the rationals, so I linear algebra'd.  This counterexample was unexpectedly small.

Comment: Ah right, there are only finitely many functions between given finite sets...

Comment: Sorry to be so dense, but I don't see why, in Robert's example, you can rule out $h_1+h_2 = (g_1 + g_2) \circ (f_1 + f_2)$ where $h_1 = g_1 \circ (f_1+f_2)$ and $h_2 = g_2 \circ (f_1 + f_2)$.

Comment: @William His argument doesn't seem to rule it out. It seems not to occur, however.

Comment: @William: Since we're talking about formal linear combinations, if $g_1 \circ f_1$ and $g_1 \circ f_2$ are different functions then $g_1 \circ (f_1 + f_2) = g_1 \circ f_1 + g_1 \circ f_2$ is not a function, but a linear combination of two functions.  There are, however, two ways to get $h_1 = g \circ f$: let's call them $g_1 \circ f_1$ and $g'_1 \circ f'_1$, where $f_1(1)=1, f_1(2)=1, f_1(3)=2, g_1(1)=1, g_1(2)=2$
and $f'_1(1)=2, f'_1(2)=2, f'_1(3)=1, g'_1(1)=2, g'_1(2)=1$, and it is possible to get $h_1$ as, e.g.,  $\left(\frac{2}{3} g_1 - \frac{1}{3} g'_1\right) \circ (2 f_1 + f'_1)$.
 

Comment: (because $g_1 \circ f'_1 = g'_1 \circ f_1$).  So it is rather more complicated than what I wrote. If $g_2 \circ f_2$ and $g'_2 \circ f'_2$ are the two ways to get $h_2$, you end up with a system of 8 equations in 8 variables representing coefficients in $(\lambda_1 g_1 + \lambda'_1 g'_1 + \lambda_2 g_2 + \lambda'_2 g'_2) \circ 
(\mu_1 f_1 + \mu'_1 f'_1 + \mu_2 f_2 + \mu'_2 f'_2) = h_1 + h_2$

       

Comment: $$ \matrix{\lambda_1 \mu_1 + \lambda'_1 \mu'_1 &= 1\cr
           \lambda'_1 \mu_1 + \lambda_1 \mu'_1 &= 0\cr
           \lambda_2 \mu_2 + \lambda'_2 \mu'_2 &= 1\cr
           \lambda'_2 \mu_1 + \lambda_1 \mu'_1 &= 0\cr
           \lambda_1 \mu_2 + \lambda'_1 \mu'_2 &= 0\cr
           \lambda'_1 \mu_2 + \lambda_1 \mu'_2 &= 0\cr
           \lambda_2 \mu_1 + \lambda'_2 \mu'_2 &= 0\cr
           \lambda'_2 \mu_1 + \lambda_2 \mu'_2 &= 0\cr}$$
And this system has no solutions.